# MVC areas and url rewriting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an Area called PlanningBoard which has a controller called PlanningBoardController and a view `in \areas\PlanningBoard\Views\PlanningBoard\Index.aspx`.

However my url says; http://localhost:55736/PlanningBoard/PlanningBoard but I'd like it to say http://localhost:55736/PlanningBoard.

I know I must be missing some rather large point about Areas but I can't see it at the moment.

Any help here would be really appreciated.

Comment: What does the RouteMap look like?

Comment: Bugger, yeah you're right.  it has planning board in front of it.  You want to answer this and I'll mark it as the correct one?

Comment: just noticed your comment I will remove my answer if XstreamNsanity posts, as it sounds like he solved it for you long before I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I see this happening is if you have your route setup to duplicate your area or you have an area hardcoded.

Check out this link for how to setup your routes for areas:

[Microsoft ASP.NET MVC - Areas](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc#_TOC3_2)

Sounds like like you have something like:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "planningboard_default",
    "planningboard/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```